# My meteor autoform wont submit, but there are no errors, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, database, meteor, schema

I am using a couple of packages in a meteor web app, including aldeed:autoform and aldeed:collection2. Together I made a schema and attached it to a database. I then auto generated a form for it, which includes a submit button. The submit button worked perfectly when I first generated it, but not when I run my meteor app it will not work once I press submit. I checked the git linked to the folder and it doesnt look like there have been any changes made that would effect this.  Is there a way that I can debug the autoform? I'm not sure what to do, any help would be great.

Here is the relevant code in my main.js file:

```
CreateLobby = new Mongo.Collection("createlobby");

CreateLobbySchema = new SimpleSchema({
  game: {
    type: String,
    label: "Game"
  },
  console: {
    type: String,
    label: "Console"
  },
  players: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Players"
  },
  mic: {
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Mic"
  },
  note: {
    type: String,
    label: "Note"
  },
  gamertag: {
    type: String,
    label: "Gamertag"
  }
});

CreateLobby.attachSchema( CreateLobbySchema );

Meteor.subscribe("createlobby");
```

and on the server main.js:

```
CreateLobby = new Mongo.Collection("createlobby");

CreateLobby.allow({
  'insert': function (userId,doc) {
    return true;
  }
});

Meteor.publish("createlobby", function(){
  return CreateLobby.find();
});
```

and html to call it:

```
{{#autoForm collection="CreateLobby" id="insertLobbyForm"         type="insert"}}
  <fieldset>
    {{> afQuickField name="game"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="console"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="players"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="mic"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="note" rows=2}}
    {{> afQuickField name="gamertag"}}
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Comment: please share your `autoform` code and submit method if contains.

Comment: there I added some code @FaysalAhmed

Comment: your mongo should be accessible from both client & server. would you try putting your collection definition in a lib folder?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I have it defined in both client and server so I don't think thats the problem

Comment: if you are using version `1.3` make sure you have imported necessary files

Comment: @faysal how do you do that?